# Creating object in an if statement

Tags: java, object, if-statement, compiler-errors

I am trying to do the following:

```
if (vehicleType == 1){
    Car vehicle = new Car();
} else if (vehicleType == 2){
    Van vehicle = new Van();
} else  {
    Bike vehicle = new Bike();
}
vehicle.setBrand("something");
```

The classes `Car`, `Bike` and `Van` all extend the class `Vehicle`, which contains `setBrand`. Therefore `vehicle.setBrand()` is always possible. So why is IntelliJ telling me "Can't find symbol."?

Note: I am doing much more with the generated object than `vehicle.setBrand()`, which is why I don't want it inside the if statements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code defines local variables inside each branch of the `if` statement, and thus they are only scoped to that block. Instead, you should **declared** the `vehicle` variable outside the `if`, but **initialize** it in the appropriate branch:

```
Vehicle vehicle; // declared here
if (vehicleType == 1) {
    vehicle = new Car(); // but initialized here
} else if (vehicleType == 2) {
    vehicle = new Van(); // or here
} else  {
    vehicle = new Bike(); // or here
}
vehicle.setBrand("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : since you have kept vehicle as local varilable its not accesible outside your respective condition blocks.

```
  Vehicle vehicle = null;
    if (vehicleType == 1){
        vehicle = new Car();
    } else if (vehicleType == 2){
        vehicle = new Van();
    } else  {
        vehicle = new Bike();
    }
    vehicle.setBrand("something");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the exact reason why inheritance is so powerful.

While using Java, every variable has a scope in which he is "alive".
Defining a variable inside a scope, the variable is recognized inside that scope.
Hence, Declaring a variable of type Vehicle before the IF statement, will make the variable persists after the if.
The main reason it is programmed in this way is that during compilation, the compiler doesn`t know which of the conditions are met (If any). while maintaining a variable with the same name in different types might be an error.

Inheritance Gives us the ability to define a common shared behavior and utilize that behavior in our code.
This is why both examples here are right.

I highly recommend you to read some more information regarding code compilation and variable scopes in java

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/variable-scope-in-java/